# Connecting Cilium Clustermesh between two separate VMs with kind-c1 and kind-c2 clusters

Tags: cluster-computing, kind, mesh-network, cilium

I followed the tutorial on https://piotrminkowski.com/2021/10/25/kubernetes-multicluster-with-kind-and-cilium/ to create two separate Cilium clusters, kind-c1 and kind-c2, on two different VMs within the same network. However, when attempting to connect them using the cilium clustermesh connect command, I encountered an error stating that the remote and local clusters have the same, non-unique name: c1.

I am unsure if it is even possible to connect Cilium Clustermesh between two separate VMs in this way. Has anyone successfully accomplished this and can offer guidance on how to resolve this error?

```
✅ Cluster access information is available:
  - <IP1>:2379
✅ Service "clustermesh-apiserver" of type "LoadBalancer" found
 Cluster Connections:
 Global services: [ min:0 / avg:0.0 / max:0 ]
ubuntu@vm2$ sudo cilium clustermesh status --context kind-c1
✅ Cluster access information is available:
  - <IP2>:2379
✅ Service "clustermesh-apiserver" of type "LoadBalancer" found
 Cluster Connections:
 Global services: [ min:0 / avg:0.0 / max:0 ]
how to connect this with cilium clustermesh
```

```
but when i try to connect it 
ubuntu@vm1$ sudo cilium clustermesh connect --destination-endpoint <IP2>:2379
✨ Extracting access information of cluster c1...
 Extracting secrets from cluster c1...
ℹ️  Found ClusterMesh service IPs: [<IP1>]
✨ Extracting access information of cluster c1...
 Extracting secrets from cluster c1...
ℹ️  Found ClusterMesh service IPs: [<IP2>]

Error: Unable to connect cluster: remote and local cluster have the same, non-unique name: c1
```

Comment: What commands did you use to create the Kind clusters on both VMs?

Comment: the same like here https://piotrminkowski.com/2021/10/25/kubernetes-multicluster-with-kind-and-cilium/

Comment: At a glance I can't see the issue with the instructions in that blog post (assuming each cluster has its own name), but I'd still recommend following [the official documentation](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/network/clustermesh/clustermesh/) instead. It's less likely to be outdated than a blog post by a third party.

Answer (score -1):

Each cluster must be assigned a unique name and cluster identification.
See documentation:
https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.9/gettingstarted/clustermesh/#prepare-the-clusters

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).